# Ember-cli - Bower not installing properly

Tags: node.js, ember.js, bower, ember-cli, bower-install

I've been trying to clone and get running an ember-cli project my team has been working on.
I do npm install and then bower install and then ember server.
This comes up:

```
Path or pattern "bower_components/moment/moment.js" did not match any files [string exception]
```

The folder that was supposed to be **moment** was named **momentjs** instead.  Weird. I renamed it and tried again:

```
Path or pattern "bower_components/ember-simple-auth/simple-auth.amd.js" did not match any files [string exception]
```

Ember-simple-auth isn't even supposed to be on this project, my team mate informed informed me that he removed it.
What's going on?

My bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "brkb-web",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.7.0",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.7",
    "loader": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
    "qunit": "~1.15.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "pikaday": "~1.2.0",
    "momentjs": "~2.8.3",
    "fancybox": "~2.1.5",
    "ember-validations": "http://builds.dockyard.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-validations/ember-validations-latest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0"
  }
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "brkb-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "0.1.1",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.6.1",
    "ember-cli": "0.0.46",
    "ember-cli-datepicker": "^1.2.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.6.7",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "express": "^4.8.5",
    "glob": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

If there's anything else you need to know, I can edit this post with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're still using the ember-cli-simple-auth package that will import the Ember Simple Auth bower package. If you want to remove Ember Simple Auth from the project you'll have to remove that as well.

Comment: Are you referring to "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.6.7" in package.json?  My team leader assures me that it being in devdependencies shouldn't be the problem or is he wrong?

Comment: Yes, he's wrong. If you use ember-cli-simple-auth you need ember-simple-auth in the `bower.json` (`ember g ember-cli-simple-auth` will add it for you) as well as ember-cli-simple-auth will import that during build time (https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth/blob/master/index.js#L9).

Comment: Cool, it works now! Thanks! I am still about the momentjs reference mismatch though, but no biggie.