# Ember error: path "vendor/loader.js/loader.js" did not match any files

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Building off: [Ember-cli - Bower not installing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520222/ember-cli-bower-not-installing-properly)

I just upgraded from ember-cli 0.0.40 to 0.1.2 and when I run the ember server I also have an issue with moment. 48 JSHint Errors of `Bad option: 'moment'.`

After JSHint is done letting me have it, I did a bad path error for loader.js:

```
Path or pattern "vendor/loader.js/loader.js" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "vendor/loader.js/loader.js" did not match any files
    at Object.multiGlob (/home/mikeumus/Downloads/RentalGeek/Development/portola-workon29oct/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:221:13)
    at /home/mikeumus/Downloads/RentalGeek/Development/portola-workon29oct/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/index.js:62:32
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/mikeumus/Downloads/RentalGeek/Development/portola-workon29oct/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:470:16)
    at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/mikeumus/Downloads/RentalGeek/Development/portola-workon29oct/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:482:17)
    at $$$internal$$publish (/home/mikeumus/Downloads/RentalGeek/Development/portola-workon29oct/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:453:11)
    at $$rsvp$asap$$flush (/home/mikeumus/Downloads/RentalGeek/Development/portola-workon29oct/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1531:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Before upgrading to ember-cli@0.1.2 I was getting an includes error for ember-cli-simple-auth. I did do `ember g ember-cli-simple-auth` and that's nifty, but the above error persists.

Comment: I upgraded from 0.0.40 to 0.1.2 yesterday and I faced a similar problem, will update you as I debug, on a side note can you `ember -v` and add the output here.

Comment: you might be pointing to loader 1.0.1 or earlier if you went straight from 0.0.40 to 0.1.2.. i think [loader](https://github.com/stefanpenner/loader.js/tree/master) is 2.0 now

Comment: Did you make sure to follow all the steps in the release notes and clear out your npm/bower folders and clear the caches for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to follow the steps on the [releases](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/releases) page to have a solid upgrade.

Specifically in your case, this is likely caused by an `app.import` in your `Brocfile.js`. One of the big changes was that bower components were moved to `/bower_components` instead of `/vendor`. That error says that something is trying to import `loader.js` from the `vendor` directory.

It could be caused by you trying to import it in your `Brocfile` or due to ember-cli not being updated properly in your `node_modules` folder. If it still references the old version, it will try to import from `vendor/` instead of `bower_components`. To fix that, just `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` to reinstall the modules.

The releases page mentions how to clear your npm cache to reinstall everything if you are still having trouble.